# Voice options for google action using dialogflow SDK

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I created some actions and intents using the dialogflow interface, I then exported the JSON files that were created. I noticed that there is a parameter:   `"voiceType": "MALE_1",` in the agent.JSON file.

My question is what other values will this voiceType key take, also is there a place I can find documentation on the structure of this agent.JSON file?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [Action Package](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ActionPackage#manifest) reference documentation shows the available types.

You can use `MALE_1`, `MALE_2`, `FEMALE_1`, and `FEMALE_2`.